# GWT ListBox has space to the right of drop down button

Tags: html, google-app-engine, gwt

The ListBox widgets on my site all look like this

[image]

instead of like this one which is not on my site, but is from another gwt site http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~ListBox

[image]

Here is how mine is initialized

```
public static ListBox chartViewBox() {
    ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
    listBox.setStyleName("listBox");
    listBox.addItem("option1");
    listBox.addItem("option2");
    return listBox;
}
```

Based on that, I do not see very much room for error. Is this a know issue? Any information would be much appreciated.

My attempts to solve/ further diagnose the problem:

-use    `listBox.setWidth(width)`

-used a much longer string as the first list item

Both approaches changed the size of the box, but the space to the right of the button persists.

Comment: Check your styles; do you have some padding set? Also, in which browser(s) are you seeing it?

Comment: have tried in chrome 28 and firefox 22. How is padding set within the ListBox? in the websites dom the drop-down button and items are all a single element.

Comment: And is there padding (or maybe border) applied to the `<select>`?

Comment: Based on your last comment, can you see if you mistyped something in your html? Did you miss a ">" at the end of some HTML tag? In the dom, you should be able to see the Listbox element separately from the items in the Listbox.

Comment: @Churro I don't think you understand how GWT works

Comment: @ Thomas Broyer yes, there was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

Set `padding-right` to `0pt` in listbox css

Answer (score 0):

By default, ListBox widgets resize to fit the longest item in it. If you want a set size, you can set a CSS "width" to it, in pixels:

```
listBox.setWidth("200px");
```

This will cause the listbox to always be 200px wide.

Comment: When I changed the width to be much, much larger than it should be, I still had the same space after the button. Same goes for adding a longer string as the default item. Sorry I should have mentioned in an "Attempt at solution" section.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. That looks very strange. May I see your site so I can inspect the DOM?